# Sublime Text plugin development: modifying the Quick Panel to add a custom text title or label?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm developing a Sublime Text 3 plugin which uses the quick panel a.k.a. the command palette.

I would like to add a textual title/label at the top of the quick panel when the user opens my plugin's quick panel menu, because my plugin runs in various modes and I want to make it clear which mode is currently running (Test, Pre-Live, Live, etc.)

Is this possible, and how?

This a mockup of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in a quick panel, no. The only thing you can provide to the quick panel display-wise is the list of items that you want the user to choose from. Each item in the list can contain multiple lines of data however (with the restriction that every row has to contain the same number of lines):

[image: Sample of quick panel]

Something like that could potentially be used to provide context on the items in the list that allows the user to know what mode you're in.

The Command Palette and the quick panel aren't the same thing (although they are visually similar); the command palette only displays commands that you can choose. By using an input handler, you can customize the display somewhat:

[image: Command Palette sample]

In this sample, `View Package File` is the selected command, but the command has control over what that text says (it's just the command name by default). You also have the power to provide a "preview" (basically any extra information that you want) about the currently selected item:

[image: Command palette with preview]

So given that, depending on your use case your command could present its interface in the command palette to give this kind of contextual clue.

Comment: I agree with OdatNurd - using a [sublime_plugin.ListInputHandler](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.ListInputHandler) might allow you to achieve something close to what you want to do but be warned `InputHandlers` are considerably more complex to implement than Quick Panels.